# Android Studio db.query Orderby use value of account between double and db number

Tags: android, sql-order-by, android-sqlite

I want to order all the values that db.query returns like this :

```
String orderby = "(("+lat+"-Latitude)+("+longi+"-Longitude)) DESC";
```

being lat and lon doubles with values and "latitude" and "longitude" the name of columns in the database

```
cursor = db.query(Table_name,projections, query, data, null, null, orderby);
```

This code runs and returns what is supposed to except for the minor fail were it doesn't order the rows.

Is there anyway to do something like what I am trying to do above?

Comment: How are your latitude and longitude fields named? Because the `ORDER BY` clause takes the field `names`, not their `values`. And these names are `comma separated`, not like `((xyz)(zxy))`.

Comment: lat and longi are doubles that have values assigned to them like this 
    double lat = 3.5555;
    double longi = 25.55555;

and the latitude and logitude are name of the columns in the database that have other values in them

Comment: So. This will work, then: `String orderby = "latitude, longitude DESC";`

Comment: but i want it to order it by the subtaction of lat with latitude plus longi less longitude like in my example

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You have to first create some `named calculated fields` and then sort on those names. I.e.: `"SELECT (" + lat + "- latitude) + (" + longi + "- longitude) AS SumOfLatAndLonDiff FROM myTable ORDER BY SumOfLatAndLonDiff DESC"`